# IllegalValueException when loading an .uml file

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, emf

I'm trying to load an uml-file to java but I fail due to an IllegalValueException. The uml-File I want to load were generated in Papyrus.

```
public Model getModel(String pathToModel, URI typesUri) {

        typesUri = URI.createFileURI(pathToModel);
        ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();

        set.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
        set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
        set.createResource(typesUri);
        Resource r = set.getResource(typesUri, true);

        Model m = (Model) EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(r.getContents(), UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);

        return m;
    }
```

When trying to get the resource I get an IllegalValueException:

```
Exception in thread "loadModel" org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value 'NoSyncdCnvrt' is not legal.
```

I searched for an answer but I still have no clue where I should locate the error.

Thanks.

Greetings

cv

Comment: could you share the .uml file ?

Comment: I don't need to, found the answer on my own, will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem. The exception was misleading. The problem was, I wanted to load a "sub"-uml-file, this file didn't provide all information and definitions which were needed.
I then imported my "main"-uml-file and it worked.

Greetings,

cv